# Obtener fecha y hora de un pais especifico - Android

Tags: c#, android, date, xamarin, datetime

Estoy intentando obtener con `Xamarin.Android` la fecha y hora de un pais, para este ejemplo la fecha y hora de `Nicaragua` (Centroamérica) independientemente de la ubicación y configuración del dispositivo siguiendo esta documentación pero me da error cada vez.

[Link de ejemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId_System_DateTime_System_String_System_String_)

[Link de formato por paises](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones)

Error:

> Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.

El error me lo da en esta linea:

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
```

Lo intente así:

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);
var HoraNic = Convert.ToString(localTime);
```

Me han dicho mucho en los comentarios que a ellos si les funciona, por lo que he intentado obtener lo deseado por otros metodos.

Intente obteniendo el UTC de la hora local y hacer un calculo para sumar algebraicamente la diferencia con el UTC de Nicaragua `UTC-06` pero esto no me funcionara correctamente si el cliente cambia la fecha de forma manual (obtendra la hora pero no la fecha si la diferencia es de un año, por ejemplo).

```
    TimeSpan ts = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).Offset;
    var ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse("-06");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dt1 = dt.AddHours(-6);
```

**Alguna idea diferente?**

Comment: No entiendo donde dices que te da el error, probé el primer bloque de código que colocaste y funcionó correctamente, no dío ningún error en tiempo de ejecución. No entiendo para que usas el segundo bloque que colocaste pues con el primer bloque basta, en este segundo bloque si existe un error en la linea `DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Now, "Central America Standard Time");` pero salta en tiempo de diseño, al compilar el código, pues el segundo argumento es de tipo `string`, no aceptado por la función.

Comment: El error me lo da en esta linea:

    var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");

Comment: Acabo de probar el código que intentaste y funcionó perfecto. :o

Comment: Asi me dijo Eduardo, no se que pasa entonces. Yo lo volvi a intentar cuando el me dijo e igual, me da error.

Comment: Hay otro metodo?

Comment: Hasta el momento lo unico que funciona (pero no me da la hora que necesito) es asi: --  var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");  --

Comment: https://docs-microsoft-com.translate.goog/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.fromserializedstring?view=net-5.0&_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=ajax%2Csc entra aqui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo utilizando esta API:

```
http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Managua
```

Y solo deserializas el Json:

```
public partial class ModelRelojNic
    {
        [JsonProperty("abbreviation")]
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("client_ip")]
        public string ClientIp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("datetime")]
        public DateTimeOffset Datetime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("day_of_week")]
        public long DayOfWeek { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("day_of_year")]
        public long DayOfYear { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dst")]
        public bool Dst { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dst_from")]
        public object DstFrom { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dst_offset")]
        public long DstOffset { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dst_until")]
        public object DstUntil { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("raw_offset")]
        public long RawOffset { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timezone")]
        public string Timezone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("unixtime")]
        public long Unixtime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("utc_datetime")]
        public DateTimeOffset UtcDatetime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("utc_offset")]
        public string UtcOffset { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("week_number")]
        public long WeekNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Lo probe y aparentemente es exactamente lo que necesito. Voy a implementarlo y te dejo saber como me va en los emuladores.

Comment: Excelente, estaré pendiente.

Comment: Hola @Jorge.Mendez, **te sugiero revisar acerca de Sock Puppets**:
[¿Por qué me quitaron puntos de reputación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196)
[¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 0):

Para conocer todas las zonas horarias que existen en tu computadora puedes usar el siguiente código, pruébalo en una aplicación de consola:

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
   Console.WriteLine(z.Id);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Las zonas horarias de tu computadora se pueden encontrar también a través del **editor de registros de** **Windows** para ello debes apretar la combinación de teclas **Windows + R**
y una vez que se abra la ventana escribir el **comando** **regedit** y pulsar la **tecla** **Enter**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando abras el editor de registros deberas navegar hasta la ruta:

**Equipo\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahi te saldrán todas las zonas horarias que están instaladas en tu computadora. Las zonas horarias instaladas dependen entre otras cosas de la versión de tu sistema operativo, de ahí que haya personas que vean determinada zona horaria y otras como en tu caso que no la vean.

Leyendo un poco(https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hora_est%C3%A1ndar_del_centro#Centroam%C3%A9rica) vi que hay varios paises de **America Central** que usan la zona horaria **"Central Standard Time"** y entre ellos está **Nicaragua**, por lo que en vez de usar el estándar que usas puedes usar este otro para la zona de **América Central**, y tendrás el mismo resultado:

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
```

No obstante si quieres crear tu propia zona horaria para determinada región puedes ver esta referencia: https://docs-microsoft-com.translate.goog/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.fromserializedstring?view=net-5.0&_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=ajax%2Csc aqui encontrarás una solución más compleja, pero con la ventaja de que puedes crear tantas zonas horarias como desees y configurarlas como desees.

Comment: Revise las zonas horarias de mi pc y si tengo Central America Standard Time asi como Central Standard Time, adjunto imagen: https://ibb.co/LQyyZ95  --  Tambien lo intente como me aconsejaste pero me arroja el mismo error:  --  var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");  --

Comment: Prueba con otras mas a ver que pasa

Comment: Si el problema persiste vas a tener que resolverlo con el otro enlace que te doy, lo complicado es que de esa forma la zona horaria la crea uno y la configura uno como quiere, mañana vemos eso